# One key recovery equivalent for Ubuntu

Tags: data-recovery, partitioning, recovery-mode

I have used **One Key** recovery tool to create a backup partition in Windows. It resets Windows just like a *factory recovery* does in an Android phone. We can even select a state of OS at a particular time as recovery.

Is there any equivalent for Ubuntu 16.04 ?

Comment: So basically you're looking for VM-like functionality where you can take snapshots and restore to a certain point, but on bare metal?

Comment: I would suggest you try OneKey, if possible. It is more or less the same you mentioned. But very easy at end user level.

Answer (score 0):

No. Generally we do this manually: boot from live session, and pick "install Ubuntu". A factory reset also erases all personal files so it basically is a re-install with format of all partitions.

The only systems with an automated factory reset are from OEM dealers (So you need to buy a system with Ubuntu on it. Dell Ubuntu systems have it) but I doubt it is very useful: when a new release comes the factory reset does not know about it so you would revert back to an older Ubuntu that might be at end of life at some point.

---

Closest you will get to a "factory reset" of your current system is the following set of commands:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt clean
reboot
```

- change the "ubuntu-desktop" to the one you want.

Comment: But the OP also wants snapshot functionality

Comment: @AndroidDev probably that can be achieved with btrfs.